# Flask как мне получить список записей конкретного пользователя?

Tags: python, flask

У меня есть две модели:
1)Модель пользователей

```
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    nickname = db.Column(db.String(100), index=True, unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), index=True, unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(100), index=True, unique=True)
    role = db.Column(db.SmallInteger, default=ROLE_USER)
    posts = db.relationship('Entry', backref='author', lazy='dynamic')
    about_me = db.Column(db.String(140))
    last_seen = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    pwdhash = db.Column(db.String(100))
```

2)Модель записей:

```
сlass Entry(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(80))
    text = db.Column(db.Text)
    pub_date = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
```

Также есть вьюшка пользователя:

```
@app.route('/user/<nickname>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def user(nickname):
    title = 'Ваша страница'
    user = User.query.filter_by(nickname=nickname).first_or_404()
    if user == None:
        flash('Пользователь ' + nickname + ' не найден.')
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    post = user.posts.order_by(Entry.pub_date.desc()).all()
    return render_template('user.html', title=title, user=user, post=post)
```

И вьюшка добавления записи:

```
@app.route('/add', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def add():
    title = 'Добавление стиха'
    form = EntryForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        add_entry = Entry(form.title.data, form.text.data, form.pub_date.data)
        db.session.add(add_entry)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Вы добавили новый стих')
        return redirect(url_for('user', nickname=g.user.nickname))
    return render_template('entry.html', title=title, form=form)
```

шаблон пользователя:

```
{% for post in posts %}
    <p>{{ entry.title }}</p>
    <pre>{{ entry.text }}</pre>
    <p>{{ entry.pub_date }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Шаблон добавления записи:

```
{% block content %}
<form class=login-form method=post action=add>
<h1 align=center>Заполните поля, для регистрации вашего стиха:</h1>
    <p>
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
    <div class=field>
    <p>{{ form.title.label }}:</p> <p>{{ form.title(size=25) }}</p>
    {% for error in form.errors.title %}
        <br><span style="color: red;">[{{ error }}]</span>
    {% endfor %}

    <div class=field>
    <p>{{ form.text.label }}:</p> <p>{{ form.text(cols=35, rows=20) }}
</p>
    {% for error in form.errors.text %}
        <br><span style="color: red;">[{{ error }}]</span>
    {% endfor %}
    </div>

    <div class=field>
    <p>{{ form.pub_date.label }}:</p> <p>{{ form.pub_date(size=20) }}</p>
        <input type="submit" value="Разместить стих">
    </div>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Так вот вопрос, как мне получить список записей ? Как сделать привязку записей к пользователю через вьюшку?

Comment: А у того юзера посты вообще есть? По коду вроде бы верно (хотя я бы переименовал `post` -> `posts`, а то путает)

Comment: gil9red - Да есть. Причём отображается на главной странице эта запись, а на странице пользователя не хочет( И переименование переменной post ничего не дало)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Необходимо добавить запись в родительскую таблицу, это можно сделать как-то так (я немного иначе использую ОРМ Алхимии):

```
@app.route('/add/<nickname>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def add(nickname):
    title = 'Добавление стиха'
    form = EntryForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = User.query.filter_by(nickname=nickname).first()
        if not user:
            flash('Пользователь ' + nickname + ' не найден.')
            return redirect(url_for('index'))
        add_entry = Entry(form.title.data, form.text.data, form.pub_date.data)
        user.posts.append(add_entry)
        db.session.add(add_entry)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Вы добавили новый стих')
        return redirect(url_for('user', nickname=g.user.nickname))
    return render_template('entry.html', title=title, form=form)
```

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/basic_relationships.html#association-object

Comment: Entry - это модель. Переименовал post в entry, ничего не изменилось.

Comment: Измените строку в Вашей вьюшке `return render_template('user.html', title=title, user=user, posts=post)`, я так понимаю Вы уже изменили шаблон и он имеет вид: `{% for entry in posts %}`

Comment: entry = user.posts.order_by(Entry.pub_date.desc()).all() ,                      return render_template('user.html', title=title, user=user, entry=entry) ,       {% for entry in entry %}
   <p>{{ entry.title }}</p>
   <pre>{{ entry.text }}</pre>
   <p>{{ entry.pub_date }}</p>
{% endfor %} вот так вот

Comment: Вьюшка:
`......
    post = user.posts.order_by(Entry.pub_date.desc()).all()
    return render_template('user.html', title=title, user=user, posts=post)`
Шаблон:
`{% for entry in posts %}
                <p>{{ entry.title }}</p>
                <pre>{{ entry.text }}</pre>
                <p>{{ entry.pub_date }}</p>
            {% endfor %}`

Comment: Тогда отладка или просто `print([i.title for i in entry])` перед return вызовите функцию - посмотрите что у Вас в entry

Comment: Так как написано выше точно не заработает( Может здесь что-то изменить? post = user.posts.order_by(Entry.pub_date.desc()).all()

Comment: При вызове функции выходит ошибка 401, ошибка доступа.

Comment: Я запутался, почему пост, если должно быть entry, Вы можете выложить код с последними изменениями?

Comment: ВЬЮШКА - entry = user.posts.order_by(Entry.pub_date.desc()).all()
    return render_template('user.html', title=title, user=user, entry=entry)               шаблон - {% for entry in entry %}
   <p>{{ entry.title }}</p>
   <pre>{{ entry.text }}</pre>
   <p>{{ entry.pub_date }}</p>
   {% endfor %}

Comment: Вроде нормально, должно работать, надо удостовериться что есть выборка из базы, допишите хотябы `print(entry)` Включите дебаг

Comment: entry = user.posts.order_by(Entry.pub_date.desc()).all()
print(entry)
return render_template('user.html', title=title, user=user, entry=entry) - добавил принт, дебаг включен, ошибки не произошло.

Comment: Что выводит принт? Желательно еще подробней:
`try:
    print([(i.title, i.text, i.pub_date) for i in entry])
except Exception as e:
    print(e)`

Comment: Принт ничего не выводит. Я обновил вопрос, наверно проблема происходит потому что к записи не добавляется id пользователя, как её решить?

Comment: я обновил ответ, может это поможет

Comment: Cпасибо за ответ) Реализовал немножко по-другому)

Comment: Пожалуйста, я бы еще посоветовал убрать индекс с поля пароль, это избыточно и в нем нет необходимости, т.к. выборку лучше сделать по пользователю и проверить пароль

Answer (score 0):

Так будет логичнее:

```
@app.route('/user/<nickname>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def user(nickname):
    title = 'Ваша страница'
    user = User.query.filter_by(nickname=nickname).first_or_404()
    if user == None:
        flash('Пользователь ' + nickname + ' не найден.')
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    posts = user.posts.order_by(Entry.pub_date.desc()).all()
    return render_template('user.html', title=title, user=user, posts=posts)



{% for post in posts %}
    <p>{{ post.title }}</p>
    <pre>{{ post.text }}</pre>
    <p>{{ post.pub_date }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Чтобы работало как у вас сейчас, замените в шаблоне:

`{% for post in posts %}` на `{% for entry in post %}`

Comment: Я понял в чём дело. При добавлении записи не присваевается id юзера.   Вот вьюшка добавлении записи:.................. @app.route('/add', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def add():
    title = 'Добавление стиха'
    form = EntryForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        add_entry = Entry(form.title.data, form.text.data, form.pub_date.data)
        db.session.add(add_entry)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Вы добавили новый стих')
      return redirect(url_for('user', nickname=g.user.nickname))
    return render_template('entry.html', title=title, form=form)